# Raspberry pi, python, detect os

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi3

I am developing a django app which will run on the raspberry pi 3 in production.

I must know at the start of the app if its running on raspberry, or in dev environment. In dev i use fake sensor data instead of the pins.

Until now i used this method:

```
from sys import platform as _platform
test_environment = "win" in _platform or "darwin" in _platform
```

This was working nice for both my pc and mac, but now i would like to deploy this to an ubuntu webserver online. Raspbian is also a linux dist, so i need something else.

This is my currently working solution, but it hurts me deep inside. Any suggestion to make it better?

```
try:
    import RPi.GPIO as gpio
    test_environment = False
except:
    test_environment = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is basically fine - I would improve it to just catch the specific error you're really looking for:

```
try:
  import RPi.GPIO as gpio
  test_environment = False
except (ImportError, RuntimeError):
  test_environment = True
```

This way if some other error occurs (out of memory, a poorly timed control-c, etc.), you won't believe you are in a test environment when you're not.  You could also add more checks just to be sure (e.g. only check for `import RPi.GPIO` if you're on linux).

Comment: The mantra in python is to "ask first ask for forgiveness later" so use try except to catch an error rather than checking if an error might occur

Comment: The RPi.GPIO library throws a `RuntimeError` on my linux machine, not an `ImportError`

Comment: Here it throws a `ModuleNotFoundError` (Linux, Py 3.7).

Comment: And the mantra is "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" EAFP :)

Answer (score 0):

There's good info in this thread:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5100/detect-that-a-python-program-is-running-on-the-pi

```
import platform
def is_raspberry_pi() -> bool:
    return platform.machine() in ('armv7l', 'armv6l')
```